# Simplifying a curve parametrization

Tags: trigonometry, parametrization

A parametric curve is described by
$$
x=\sin t,\,\,\,y=\sin (t+\frac{\pi}{6}).
$$
Is there a way to show that
$$
y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}
$$
without using the property $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b \cos a$?

Comment: Why can't we use $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b \cos a$?

Comment: Your answer is only correct for $t\in [0,\pi]$. When $t\in [\pi,2\pi]$, there's a minus sign in front of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(t+\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin t+\frac{1}{2}\cos t$, we have $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Without using the formula, I feel like
$$\arcsin y-\frac{\pi}{6}=t=\arcsin x.$$